# Git: Pull from other remote

Tags: git, github

I have created a fork from a project on GitHub.
How can I now pull changes from the project that I forked from?

Comment: The title is different from the question. It should be Pull from other remote

Comment: Could you please edit the title? I came here from this search:

https://www.google.com.au/search?client=opera&q=how+to+pull+from+another+branch&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8. To pull from another branch do this: `git pull origin branch_name_you_want_to_pull_from:branch_name_to_pull_to

Comment: Moved this Q&A to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516415/git-pull-a-branch-within-the-same-local-repository/58516416#58516416.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

`git pull` is really just a shorthand for `git pull <remote> <branchname>`, in most cases it's equivalent to `git pull origin master`. You will need to add another remote and pull explicitly from it. This page describes it in detail:

http://help.github.com/forking/

Comment: Thanks! Should I add the "upstream" to the same project folder as my origin?


Eg.

cd project
git remote add upstream git://github.com/somename/original-project.git

Comment: After such pulling i see merge prompt, but not just clean another branch

Comment: Igor Zevaka : Is there any way to pull all branches from a upstream remote ?

Answer (score 68):

`upstream` in the github example is just the name they've chosen to refer to that repository.  You may choose any that you like when using `git remote add`.  Depending on what you select for this name, your `git pull` usage will change.  For example, if you use:

`git remote add upstream git://github.com/somename/original-project.git`

then you would use this to pull changes:

`git pull upstream master`

But, if you choose origin for the name of the remote repo, your commands would be:

To name the remote repo in your local config: `git remote add origin git://github.com/somename/original-project.git`

And to pull: `git pull origin master`