# How do you pull from a different branch than the master using git?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to pull some files from a different branch than the master branch.

However, I get an error:

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: could not read from the remote repository
```

Here is my branches:
[image]

And here are my commands to attempt to pull:
[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Pull from other branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257196/git-pull-from-other-branch)

Answer (score 3):

You have never cloned from your github repository (or set the remote afterwards).

- Either create your local repository by cloning your github repo:

  ```
  git clone git@github.com:username/repository.git
  ```
- Or set the origin remote after initializing the empty repository:

  ```
  git init
  git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repository.git
  git fetch origin
  ```

Comment: would running either the 1st or 2nd set of commands pull from the master or gh-pages branch?

Comment: upon running either commands, I get a "permanently added the RSA host key for..." "permission denied (publickey)"

Comment: @user1631224: The clone will initially contain the state of the remote master branch. The second sequence of commands will sync your repository databases but will not checkout the new branch state. You can either use `git pull`/`git merge` or `git checkout` to do that (depending on what you want to do exactly). If you don't have local work yet, checkout should be enough.

Comment: @user1631224: have you associated your private key with your github profile and given it permissions for your repository?

Answer (score 0):

Git is a fully distributed version system. This means that you do not work on the remote server directly, instead you work locally and pull and push changes between the local and remote repo.

First, you need to have your repository local, you can do this several ways, but an easy way is to git-clone a repository from a remote site, i.e. on github: 
`git clone ssh://git@github.com/username/repository.git`

From the [git-clone man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html):

> Clones a repository into a newly created directory, creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository (visible using git branch -r), and creates and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active branch.

This means that it will checkout the default branch of most likely master.

If you include the branch flag to git clone, you will get a specific branch, from [git-clone man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html):

> --branch 
>   -b 
>   Instead of pointing the newly created HEAD to the branch pointed to by the cloned repository’s HEAD, point to  branch instead. In a non-bare repository, this is the branch that will be checked out. --branch can also take tags and detaches the HEAD at that commit in the resulting repository.

So you could run
`git clone -b gh_pages ssh://git@github.com/username/repository.git`
to checkout a specific branch.

Or if you already have cloned the repo, you can setup a new branch and run:
`git checkout -b gh_pages --track origin/gh_pages`

This will checkout a new branch locally and name it gh_pages. It will track the remote origin branch of gh_pages, so that when you push and pull, it will use origin/gh_pages.

Comment: when I run git clone -b gh_pages ssh://git@... I get "cloning into.." but then I get a "permission denied (publickey)"

Comment: you need to setup your ssh key on the server or remote host to allow for git over ssh - if it is github or another service - you can do this in your profile.