# how to merge from one remote branch to remote master in git?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

Here is my work-flow in git at work:
please correct if you find anything bad or if my understanding is incorrect;

I run

```
git branch -vv
 dev               0ac3415 [origin/dev: behind 29] 
 master            8d9d84f [origin/master: behind 109]  -- Merge branch 'dev'
 XXX_dev ad3a2df [origin/XXX_dev: ahead 4] Merge branch 'XXX_dev' of my.company.com:AAA_BBB_CCC into XXX_dev
XXX_master 8c55372 [origin/XXX_master] Merge branch 'master' of my.company.com:AAA_BBB_CCC
```

Here is my understanding:

1) I have four branches in my local which are *dev, master,XXX_dev and XXX_master*. Each of these branches track remote branches with same name

2) I am in XXX_dev branch. If I have local commits in XXX_dev and do a `git push`,
all the changes from *XXX_dev* in local will be merged into remote branch *XXX_dev*. Similarly when I issue `git pull`, any changes from *origin/XXX_dev* ONLY will be pulled and merged into my local *XXX_dev*. Is this correct? or issuing `git pull` does a git fetch and merge for all branches ?

3) Our development statergy is all changes are in `XXX_dev` which will get pushed into `origin/XXX_dev`. After QA team approves that `origin/XXX_dev` build is stable, I will do a merge into origin/`XXX_master`.

so how would I do this merge? I.e from one remote repository into another.

I am thinking something along this line..

`git push origin/XXX_dev origin/XXX_master` -- but not sure if this is the right way to do it?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you and a happy new year :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do a `git push`, all the changes from *XXX_dev* in local will be merged into remote branch *XXX_dev*.

You can't merge with push, since you can't resolve conflicts. Push requires there not to be any changes on the remote branch; so push merely uploads the "missing" commits.

> Is this correct? or issuing `git pull` does a git fetch and merge for all branches ?

It fetches everything, and merges the current branch. It is impossible to merge all the branches; again, how would you resolve conflicts?

> so how would I do this merge?

Why does it have to be remote? If the branches are tracked, just merge `XXX_dev` to `XXX_master` and push.

Comment: 1) so I need to checkout each branch and do a merge again. 2) what if I dont have XXX_master in my local but only XXX_dev. A scenario that is likely to happen for interns here.

Comment: so "push merely uploads the missing commits"; but when somebody else issue a git pull, he gets all the commits I pushed and his HEAD will be pointing to the latest commit correct? Thanks for explaning

Comment: Re: interns: Either they are allowed to commit to master, in which case it makes sense for them to track the branch, or they are not, in which case they shouldn't be doing it and someone else should handle the merge into master. Merging into a branch you don't have makes little sense to me, either way (although I can't think of a reason why it would not work, but didn't test). Re: git pull: Almost. If they are on that branch, `git pull` will merge your branch into theirs and update `HEAD` to the *merge commit* (not your latest commit), unless it's a simple fast-forward.

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257196/git-pull-from-other-branch, "git pull" is equivalent to "git pull origin master" in which case it is pulling only master. so how is my XXX_dev branch gets merged with origin/XXX_dev if I issue "git pull" from XXX_dev branch

Comment: It is only equivalent to `git pull origin master` if you are on `master` branch, your default remote is `origin`, and your `master` branch is tracked. If you are on `XXX_dev` branch, your default remote is `origin` and your `XXX_dev` branch is tracked, then `git pull` is equivalent to `git pull origin XXX_dev`. (The linked answer even says "in most cases".)

Comment: wonderful! Thanks for great explanation. One final question though. lets say I am in branch in XXX_dev and issue a git pull. my local XXX_dev is updated with commits from origin. now if I checkout to another branch say YYY_dev, in this case `git pull` has already fetched all the commits for all the branches (as I understand from your answer by line "It fetches everything, and merges the current branch."). so I just need to issue merge command correct?

Comment: Indeed, after `fetch` (or `pull`), you can `checkout` each branch that you are interested in and `merge` (or `pull`).