# define git alias for pulling remote branch

Tags: git, bash, command-line

I recently began adding git aliases to my workflow, but have not figured out how to handle the following scenario.

Multiple times a day I pull down the latest remote branch into my local `master` with `git pull git@github.com:Matt-Dionis/angular2-tour-of-heroes.git` for example.

What I would like to do is assign an alias such as `git pull latest-tour` where `latest-tour` refers to that ssh address.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `git remote add latest-tour git@github.com:Matt-Dionis/angular2-tour-of-heroes.git`

Comment: There are many ways to do it but I'd go with the one @JeffPuckettII said: just add them as a remote, then you can `git fetch` from them, view commits with `git log latest-tour/master`, merge and/or rebase, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [Git Basics - Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes), you can **[add multiple remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#_adding_remote_repositories)**. A `git pull/fetch` will use by default the remote named `origin`.
But you can at any time fetch from any of the other remotes you might have defined.

As mentioned by [Jeff Puckett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4233593/jeff-puckett):

```
 git remote add latest-tour git@github.com:Matt-Dionis/angular2-tour-of-heroes.git 
 git fetch latest-tour
```

You can the [pull from a different remote and different branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2257205/6309):

```
git push latest-tour master
```

Comment: is this a local alias ? or is it added to the repo for others to use ?

Comment: @eranotzap It is remote name, that is: a local config setting, that you can see in `<path/to/my/local/repo>/.git/config`. It is local, meaning only valid for your local repository. Not for others.