# git pull a branch within the same local repository

Tags: git

How do I pull changes from one branch to another branch within the same local repository?

Context: in the process of developing a feature, I then started developing a feature on another branch that would be needed for the first feature. However, the second feature cannot actually be pushed as-is to the develop branch, as it contains unused code. So I want to pull the changes from the second feature in another branch, to the first feature in the other branch.

Comment: Pull is basically a "fetch from remote + then merge". Since there is no remote involved, you can just use `git merge`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and is simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `git pull` = `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (or some other Git command).
2. `git fetch` means *get commits from another Git*.
3. `git merge` means *merge commits I already have in my repository*.

If you don't have the commits yet, you need step 2.  In your case, you *do* have the commits—so all you need is `git merge` (or the other command you were going to have `git pull` run as the second of the two commands).

Let's add to this `git push`:

4. `git push` means *send commits to another Git*.  It's as close as there is to the opposite of `git fetch`.  Its opposite is *not* `git pull`: `git pull` is a *combination* command; `git push` and `git fetch` are the two fundamental transfer-commits-from-one-repository-to-another commands.

Note that when you use `git fetch`, you take commits from their Git—the other Git, which is typically one you call `origin`—and put them into your repository, but then also *label* those commits with names like `origin/master` and `origin/feature`.  These labels, which we can call *remote-tracking names*, remember that *their* Git—the one over on `origin`—used the name `master` or the name `feature` to remember those specific commits.

Where `git push` differs, quite a bit, is that after sending new commits *to* their repository, your Git asks their Git to set *their* **branch** names.  That is, if you run `git push origin master`, you have your Git send their Git any new commits you have that they don't (and that they need), and then your Git says: *now that you have commit `a123456...`*—or whatever its hash ID is—*now that you have the commit, set **your** `master` to identify that commit.*  There is no remote-tracking name involved: your Git tells their Git to set its *branch* names.

It's always safe to run `git fetch`.  This either picks up some new commits (and doesn't touch any of *your* branches), or it doesn't pick up anything new (and still doesn't touch any of your branches).

It's up to the *other* Git to decide if it likes your `git push`: you send it commits if needed, then ask it to set its branch names, which it will do if they think it's safe.  You can send them a command—*set your branch names!*—using `--force` to override it if they think it's not safe and you think you know better, but it's wise to make sure you really do know better, first.

When and whether it is safe to run `git merge` is something you should decide on your own.  Unfortunately, if you use `git pull`, you've decided that it's safe regardless of what happens in the `git fetch` step.  Sometimes it still is safe anyway—especially if *you* control the other Git repository too—but I prefer to *avoid* `git pull` in general.  I prefer to break it into its two component parts.  This gives me a chance to look at what `git fetch` actually fetched, using `git log`, before I decide on merge, rebase, or something else entirely (perhaps even a forced push, although that would be extremely rare).

Comment: While I have used git for some time, this is a helpful explanation, and particularly so for those even newer to git than myself who may come across this question in future!

Answer (score 1):

I might prefer to handle this completely locally.  You could try:

```
# from feature-child
git rebase feature-mother
git checkout feature-mother
git merge feature-child
git push origin feature-mother
```

This strategy uses a rebase to bring the `feature-child` branch, where you accidentally did all the work, up to date with the latest `feature-mother` changes, at least locally.  Then, we do a fast-forward merge of `feature-child` into `feature-mother` to bring in your work to the latter branch.  Finally, we can push `feature-mother` to the repository, if needed.

Comment: Cool, thanks, this is a better answer! Haven't tested it yet but it looks like it would work.

Comment: @JamesRay What you did is fine, but it feels like shooting a missile at a distant target.  If it hits correctly, you're OK, if not, maybe there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I pushed my local changes on the branch of feature that contains dependent code for the other feature, for brevity I will call the former the `feature-mother`, and the latter branch `feature-child`, i.e.: `git checkout feature-mother; git push`. Then I ran:

`git pull origin feature-mother:feature-child`.

This worked for me. Whether the first paragraph was necessary, or whether there is a way to pull changes from a local branch, is unknown to me.